# GuzzleHttp\Client ignores base path in base_url

Tags: php, guzzle

I'm using Guzzle in a set of PHPUnit-powered tests for a REST API.

I create my client as follows:

```php
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

$client = new Client(['base_url' => ['http://api.localhost/api/{version}', ['version' => '1.0']]]);
```

This works fine, and I can make requests using the following code:

```php
$request = $client->createRequest('GET', '/auth');
$request->setBody(Stream::factory(json_encode(['test'=>'data'])));
$response = $client->send($request);
$decodedResponse = $response->json();
```

However, Guzzle is ignoring the `/api/{version}` part of the base URL and makes the request to here:

```html
http://api.localhost/auth
```

However, I would have expected it to make the request here:

```html
http://api.localhost/api/1.0/auth
```

Have I mis-read the documentation and my expected behaviour is thus wrong, or is there some other option I need to enable to get it to append the `/auth` url to the `/api/1.0` base path when making the request?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30874624/10043987 solved my problem

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here are examples for `Guzzle 7` (`7.4.1`) of what [Michael Dowling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25291511/2450431) wrote

```php
$client = new Client(['base_uri' => 'http://my-app.com/api/']);
$response = $client->get('facets'); // no leading slash - append to base
//    http://my-app.com/api/facets

$client = new Client(['base_uri' => 'http://my-app.com/api/']);
$response = $client->get('facets/'); // no leading slash - append to base // ending slash preserved
//    http://my-app.com/api/facets/

$client = new Client(['base_uri' => 'http://my-app.com/api/']);
$response = $client->get('/facets'); // leading slash - absolute path - base path is lost
//    http://my-app.com/facets

$client = new Client(['base_uri' => 'http://my-app.com/api']); // no ending slash in base path - ignored
$response = $client->get('facets');
//    http://my-app.com/facets

$client = new Client(['base_uri' => 'http://my-app.com/api']);
$response = $client->get('/facets'); // leading slash - absolute path - base path is lost
//    http://my-app.com/facets
```

Comment: I've switched this to the accepted answer as the examples are really helpful. :)

Answer (score 24):

You're using an absolute path in your requests, so it's overriding the path set in the base URL. Guzzle follows RFC 3986 when combining URLs: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.2

Comment: I knew it would be something obvious. Thanks. :)

Comment: So what did you do? Just forget the template service and move on with your life?

Comment: I'm not sure what that means. You just need to remove the leading "/" from URLs to make them relative to the base URL's path.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelDowling. Mind putting that last comment in your answer?

Comment: I also had to add a trailing slash to my `base_uri` - Guzzle 6

Comment: Nobody wants to read an RFC to figure out the answer. Including examples would seriously improve the answer.

Answer (score 6):

I have a sort of oblique answer that might help someone who's predisposed to the same type of typos as I am.

It's `base_uri`, and that's "**uri**". Not `base_url`, as in "**url**".

The consequence of setting a `base_url` is similar to the problem described by OP - the request won't build on the configured base.

Comment: As a side note, in 2014 when the issue occurred, it was `base_url` with an L. The current version uses `base_uri`. My issue was that I was starting the call itself with an initial slash, so instead of getting calls to http://api.localhost/api/{version}/auth as expected, I was getting calls to http://api.localhost/auth.