# base_uri not being based from guzzle client instantiation

Tags: guzzle, lumen

I'm using lumen trying to set up simple API requests via guzzle.

The problem is the base_uri parameter doesn't appear to be passed correctly on the initial `new Client()`.

Simplified example:

```php
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

$client = new Client([
 'base_uri' => 'https://siteurl.com/api/v2'
]);
```

Then calling the api via get

```php
$res = $client->get('orders', [
    'query' => [
            'status' => 'completed'
    ]
]);
```

does not work. I've been careful not to use absolute urls like `/orders`. If I bypass `base_uri` entirely and just add it on the get method `$client->get('https://siteurl.com/api/v2/orders')`, it works.

I'm using:

```json
"laravel/lumen-framework": "5.0.*",
"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.0"
```

***Follow-up:**

I added the debug flag so I could compare the headers, and the noticeable difference is in the get request line.

Absolute url in the get method (bypassing base_uri):
> GET /api/v2/orders?status=completed HTTP/1.1

Using base_uri (version is being stripped):
> GET /api/orders?status=completed HTTP/1.1

Comment: Did you happen to figure this out?  I am having the exact same issue, and I do have my base_uri terminated with a / as suggested in the answer.

Comment: Disregard my comment.  I was looking at the wrong documentation for my guzzle version.  The newest version uses base_uri and I am back on a previous version that used base_url instead.

Comment: @PaulZepernick Did the fix I suggested work for you?

Comment: @AvindraGoolcharan I needed to use base_url instead of base_uri.  I was looking at the latest doc which says to use base_uri, but I am using version 5.3 so I needed to look at this doc http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/5.3/ which says to use base_url.  The key was changed from base_url -> base_uri in the new version.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You need to terminate your base_uri with a forward slash /

E.g.,

```php
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

$client = new Client([
    'base_uri' => 'https://siteurl.com/api/v2/'
]);
```

Edit: **Note** that base_uri is for Guzzle 6+, whereas previous versions used base_url.

Comment: Your last comment is what saved me. Confirmed that using `base_url` with a forward slash ending the url works with Guzzle 5

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I'm using Guzzle 6.3.3. My client is created as follows (sensitive data obfuscated)

    `$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client([
       'base_uri' => 'https://****.corehr.com/ws/****/corehr/'
    ]);`

Then I create a request as follows

    $request = GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request(
        'GET',
        '/v1/filter/active/'
    );

Then when I make a call like `$client->send($request)` the endpoint called is `https://****.corehr.com/v1/filter/active` instead of `https://****.corehr.com/ws/****/corehr/v1/filter/active`.

Comment: Sorry, disregard my last comment. The problem is that the relative url must not start with `/`. So `$request = GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request( 'GET', 'v1/filter/active/' );` works as expected.